# Iterate through lines and compare in Python

Tags: python

I am analyzing genome sequencing data and having a problem that I can't identify. I am using an input fastq file containing about 5 million sequence reads as shown here:

```
1    Unique Header    #Read 1
2    AAAAAA.....AAAAAA    #Sequence Read 1
3    +
4    ??AA@F    #Quality of Read 1
5    Unique Header    #Read 2
6    ATTAAA.....AAAAAA
7    +
8    >>AA?B
9    Unique Header    #Read 3
10   ATAAAA.....AAAAAA
11   +
12   >>AA?B
```

The idea is to then iterate through this file and compare the Sequence read lines (lines 2 and 6 above). If the first and last six chars of a sequence are unique enough (Levenshtein distance of 2) then the full sequence and its corresponding three lines are written to an output file. Otherwise, it is ignored.

My code appears to do this when I use a small test file, but when I then analyze a full fastq file, it appears that two many sequences are written to the output file.

I have my code below, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Code:

```
def outputFastqSimilar():
    target = open(output_file, 'w') #Final output file that will contain only matching acceptable reads/corresponding data

    with open(current_file, 'r') as f: #This is the input fastq
        lineCharsList = [] #Contains unique concatenated strings of first and last 6 chars of read line

        headerLine = next(f)  #Stores the header information for each line
        counter = 1

        for line in f:
            if counter == 1: 
                lineChars = line[0:6]+line[145:151] #Identify first concatenated string of first/last 6 chars
                lineCharsList.append(lineChars)

                #Write first read/info to output
                target.write(headerLine)
                target.write(line)
                nextLine = next(f)
                target.write(nextLine)
                nextLine = next(f)
                target.write(nextLine)
                headerLine = next(f)    #Move to next header
                counter+=1

            elif counter > 1:
                lineChars = line[0:6]+line[145:151] #Get first/last six chars from next read

                different_enough = True
                for i in lineCharsList: #Iterate through list and compare with current read
                    if distance(lineChars, i) < 2: #Levenshtein distance
                        different_enough = False
                        for skip in range(3): #If read too similar, skip over it
                            try:
                                check = line #Check for additional lines in file
                                headerLine = next(f) #Move to next header
                            except StopIteration:
                                break

                    elif distance(lineChars, i) >= dist_stringency & different_enough == True: #If read is unique enough, write to output
                        lineCharsList.append(lineChars)
                        target.write(headerLine)
                        target.write(line)
                        nextLine = next(f)
                        target.write(nextLine)
                        nextLine = next(f)
                        target.write(nextLine)
                        try:
                            check = line
                            headerLine = next(f)
                        except StopIteration:
                            break

    target.close()
```

Desired output of test file would be the following, where all reads are unique, but the read on line 10 has a Levenshtein distance < 2 to the read on line 2 so would not be included in the output:

```
1    Unique Header    #Read 1
2    AAAAAA.....AAAAAA    #Sequence Read 1
3    +
4    ??AA@F    #Quality of Read 1
5    Unique Header    #Read 2
6    ATTAAA.....AAAAAA
7    +
8    >>AA?B
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare each sequence with all other sequences?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the fastq file?

Comment: @TheNightman can you please post the desired output of the test file you have shown above

Comment: @nivix zixer, there are almost certainly duplicate sequences. Tanmaya Meher, will do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're testing whether each read is different enough from **any** previous read, but what you really want is the set of reads that are different from **all** previous reads.

You could set a flag `different_enough = True` before you enter this loop:`for i in lineCharsList:`

Then, when you test if `distance(lineChars, i) < 2` set it to `different_enough = False`.

Don't print out anything inside the loop, wait until after it has completed and then check the status of `different_enough`. If your read passed every comparison it will still be True, so print out the read. If if even one read was too similar it will be False.

That way you'll only print the read if it passed every comparison.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice this. This helped, but did not entirely solve the issue.

Comment: You need to do the `if different_enough` test outside of the for loop for this strategy. Finish doing all of the comparisons first. Then after the loop finishes, check `different_enough` and write to the file if it's still True.